Image Invariance for SPD matrices
Given $V \in \mathcal{R}^{n \times m}$ having full column rank and $M \in \mathcal{R}^{m \times m}$ Symmetric Positive Definite.
How can I deduce that Image$(V M V^T)$ = Image$(V)$?
I know that this could be seen as a T-Congruence transformation, but all I've found in the literature is properties of T-congruent matrices assuming that $V$ is a square matrix. These properties where also only related to the rank and null spaces, and not the image. I'm honestly not sure how to go about this.
Any help would be appreciated, a link to a reference would also be very helpful.
Thank you!

If you're sufficiently comfortable with nullspaces, then another approach you can take here is noting that $\text{image}(P) = \text{Nul}(P^T)^\perp$, so that it suffices to show that
$$
\text{Nul}(VMV^T) = \text{Nul}(V^T).
$$

The point of this is $V$ is injective so it has a (choice of) left inverse $U$ and rank is submultiplicative.  $\implies \text{rank}\big(M\big)= \text{rank}\big((UV)M(V^TU^T)\big)\leq \text{rank}\big(V MV^T\big)\leq \text{rank}\big(M\big)$
$\implies \text{rank}\big(M\big)=\text{rank}\big(V MV^T\big)$
This holds over any field and has nothing to do with $M$ being invertible or symmetric or PSD, etc. Your problem statement implicitly tells you that $\text{rank}\big(M\big) = \text{rank}\big(V\big)$ which gives the result.

From the fact that $\text{Image}(PQ) \subset \text{Image}(P)$, we can deduce that
$$
\text{image}(VMV^T) = \text{image}(V[MV^T])\subset \text{image}(V).
$$
To deduce the reverse containment, we can use the fact that $V$ having full column-rank means that there exists a matrix $V^+$ such that $V^+V = I$, where $I$ denotes the size-$n$ identity matrix (one option is to take $V^+$ to be the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse of $V$). This in turn means that
$$
I = I^T = (V^+V)^T = V^T(V^+)^T.
$$
With that established, we note that
\begin{align*}
\text{image}(V) &= 
\text{image}(VMIM^{-1}) 
\\ & = \text{image}(VM V^T(V^+)^T  M^{-1}) 
\\ & = 
\text{image}(VM V^T[(V^+)^T  M^{-1}]) \subset \text{image}(VMV^T).
\end{align*}
Thus, $\text{image}(VMV^T) \subset \text{image}(V)$ and $\text{image}(V) \subset \text{image}(VMV^T)$. The conclusion follows.

As an alternative proof: use the general fact that $\text{image}(P) = \text{image}(PP^T)$ together with the fact that
$$
\text{image}(V) = \text{image}(VM^{1/2}),
$$
where we take $M^{1/2}$ to be the (unique symmetric positive definite) square root of $M$.
